# Deep linking Salesforce with external systems

Tags: lightning-web-components, integration, deep-linking

Client has a specific requirement to deep link Salesforce to his other systems. He expects to have them deep linked in two ways:

1. UI - LWCs, VF pages etc. - done via REST outbound calls from SF to external system via Request-Reply integration pattern
2. Record redirects - clicking a link on a record would redirect a user to the external system.

My question is, because I don't know much about implementing this, is it generally a good idea to form redirects based on external IDs for example? Or should this always be implemented via an LWC?

My apologies for the way my question is formulated. I am looking for an experienced opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of implementation is more common than one might think. It is a good idea to map your requirements and communicate effectively with the owner of the external system. Salesforce will redirect users to the external system using hyperlinks. Therefore, it is crucial for the URL structure of that system to be stable. If any changes are needed in the future, they should be communicated to the team responsible for the Salesforce instance. They can then update formulas, links, code, and other relevant components.

In this scenario, it is not merely a matter of being a good idea; it is a requirement and the appropriate way to implement it. If the URLs are static or stable enough, you don't need Lightning Web Components (LWCs). You can utilize the HYPERLINK function in formula fields, for instance, and place these fields on layouts as needed.

However, this situation differs slightly for custom screens built with LWC, Aura, or Visualforce. While the same principles I mentioned earlier still apply, it is likely beyond the scope of an admin user to take action. In such cases, you will most likely require the assistance of a developer to update the code if the URL format changes.

Comment: Understood. How about authentication in the external systems to which the user is being redirected? Could this be done using SAML or OpenId Connect?

Comment: You should probably see what is supported by your external system and which one of the two is going to be the Identity Provider in this relationship. I suggest reading about the subject because the usage might differ on your use case. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.sso_use_cases.htm&type=5